# How to get dob value in magento 1.9 using custom jquery?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Hi, 
I am trying to call the dob value in createpost but in that i did not get the value of dob in magento 1.9.

```
<div class="tab-content " id="registerTab">
            <h4 class="title">Register to your Tresmode Account</h4>
            <div class="account-create">
                <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
                <form action="<?php echo $customerBlock->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="register-form" class="scaffold-form">
                    <div class="fieldset">
                         <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                         <input type="hidden" name="login" id="reg_val" value="" />
                        <!-- <p class="required">* Required Fields</p> -->
                        <ul class="form-list">
                            <li class="fields row">
                                <div class="customer-name">
                                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($customerBlock->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="email_address2" class="required"><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="email" id="email_address2" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo $customerBlock->escapeHtml($customerBlock->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $customerBlock->quoteEscape($customerBlock->__('Email Address')) ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry">

                                </div>
                            </li>


                            <li class="fields row"> 

                                    <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
                                    <?php //if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $_dob->setDate($customerBlock->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
                                        <?php// endif ?>

                            </li> 

                            <li class="mobile-No">
                                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em>Mobile Number</label>
                                <div class="input-box">

                                    <input type="tel" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="phone" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $customerBlock->escapeHtml($customerBlock->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $customerBlock->quoteEscape($customerBlock->__('Telephone')) ?>" class="input-text validate-phone required-entry" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" maxlength="10">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="fields">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em>Password</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $customerBlock->quoteEscape($customerBlock->__('Password')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em>Confirm Password</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $customerBlock->quoteEscape($customerBlock->__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="reg-checkbox">
                                <input class="styled-checkbox" id="termsconditions" type="checkbox" value="value1">
                                <label for="termsconditions">YES! By Creating An Account I Agree To Tresmode Terms & Conditions.</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reg-checkbox">
                                <input class="styled-checkbox" id="specialOffer" type="checkbox" value="value1">
                                <label for="specialOffer">Sign Me Up To Receive Special Offer Updates </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-set">
                        <!-- <button type="submit" title="Register" class="button"><span><span>Register</span></span></button> -->
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Register')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Register') ?></span></span></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your register.phtml code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai added in question please see

Comment: You have not turned it on from magento admin. Why you directly choosen to comment out the code? Can you enable it from admin.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it. But not working